# How to put together data from two tables in database?

Tags: sql, select

I have two tables in a database, like so (simplified for question purposes):

[image: the two tables I have]

I don't want to modify the existing tables or create a new one, but I would like to put all of this data into a consolidated object in my code like so:

[image: the data I want]

There are actually more properties in TABLE2 but I am only interested in food and color.

I'm completely new to databases so bear with me - is there a simple way to do this? What I'm thinking so far is doing

```
SELECT * FROM TABLE1

SELECT PROPERTY_VALUE, UNIQUE_IDENTIFIER 
FROM TABLE2 
WHERE PROPERTY_NAME = 'Favorite Color'

SELECT PROPERTY_VALUE, UNIQUE IDENTIFIER 
FROM TABLE2 
WHERE PROPERTY_NAME = 'Favorite Food'
```

and then putting them together somehow... Is there a better way? Or if not, where do I go from here?

Comment: This is an EAV ([Entity, Attribute, Value](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Entity%E2%80%93attribute%E2%80%93value_model)) schema design.  Such designs are notoriously difficult to query, as you're finding out.  You will need to join your three queries; the second two could be sub-queries in the FROM clause, but you can simply join with table 2 twice.  Can you afford to use (inner) JOIN, or will you be obliged to use LEFT (outer) JOIN?  Probably the latter, as the rules enforcing integrity that will allow the former are tricky to write.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There are a couple ways to do this, but regardless of which one you use, *you generally need to know the number and names of the columns in the result set at the time you write the query*.  I can give you Favorite Food and Favorite Color, but if there's any other properties in that table you won't see them. There is no way to automate that with vanilla sql; you must use dynamic sql or a client-side language if you want to get arbitrary properties from that kind of schema.

With that constraint out of the way, let's look at one way you could do this:

```
SELECT m.unique, m.last_name, m.first_Name, s1.property_Value As Favorite_Food, s2.property_Value As Favorite_Color
FROM Table_1 m
LEFT JOIN Table_2 s1 ON s1.unique = m.unique and s1.property_Name = 'Favorite Food'
LEFT JOIN Table_2 s2 ON s2.unique = m.unique and s2.property_Name = 'Favorite Color'
```

Another option is to use the [PIVOT keyword](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177410%28v=sql.105%29.aspx), but until we know more details of your actual data, the join above is sufficient.

Comment: I do know the names of the columns at the time of writing the query. This works; thank you so much!

Answer (score 1):

Here is the code to create new table TABLE3 of two existing tables, if you don't need to create new table, just throw out the first line (INSERT).

```
INSERT INTO TABLE3 
SELECT 
    TABLE1.`UNIQUE IDENTIFIER`, 
    TABLE1.`First Name`, 
    TABLE1.`Last Name`, 
    TABLE2a.`Property Value`, 
    TABLE2b.`Property Value` 
 FROM TABLE1
 INNER JOIN TABLE2 AS TABLE2a 
     ON TABLE2a.`UNIQUE IDENTIFIER`=TABLE1.`UNIQUE IDENTIFIER`
 INNER JOIN TABLE2 AS TABLE2b 
     ON TABLE2b.`UNIQUE IDENTIFIER`=TABLE1.`UNIQUE IDENTIFIER` 
 WHERE 
     TABLE2a.`Property Name`='Favorite Food' 
 AND
     TABLE2b.`Propery Name`='Favorite Color';
```

Answer (score 0):

What about a join?

```
select * from TABLE1 join TABLE2 on TABLE1.UNIQUE_IDENTIFIER = TABLE2.UNIQUE_IDENTIFIER;
```

Creates the joined table with all tables of both single tables. If you only want specific columns, replace the * by your choice of columns.

Comment: The problem with this is that I am interested in columns from TABLE1, and rows from TABLE2